# cant access all submenus from an item in concret5

Tags: concrete5

I am using concret5 in a website, and I have a weird issue that I can not access to all sub menus from one item... I changed all possible but no results, I can see the page on the sitemap, and the urls are fine, but whenever I click on it I go directly to not found page, any idea, advice or something else I should check for this?

sorry for the few details, but there is nothing more I can describe or say (the site is local hosted).

Answer (score 1):

The only thought I have (without more details or the live site) is that pretty URLs are on but not supported.

Ie, your autonav block (and other blocks that create links) think you have pretty URLs enabled, so they provide links like /about-section/contact-us. However, pretty URLs aren't enabled, so concrete5 isn't called for anything other than /index.php .

THe quick test for this is to disable pretty URLs (type "pretty") into the intelligent search bar. If it starts generating links in the form /index.php/about-section/contact-us, and those work, then this is your problem. You can then re-enable, but be sure to create the .htaccess file as it tells you to.

Answer (score 0):

What submenu are you talking about exactly?

If it's the block edit submenu,
be sure to check the permissions on the block / area!
Either the permissions on a single block have to be changed, or the page type might be set up with restricted area permissions.

I had the same issue many times...